# How to show first and last date ticks in the navigator - Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was wondering if it's possible to show the first and last date ticks in the navigator.

[image]

I added xAxis to the navigator and created tickPositioner function to return the linear ticks positions with the first and last.
But this is not working as I would expect.

```
[This is my code][1].

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Sayed110/3Lfhq5ze/22/
```

Comment: can you add more details, not able to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The last label is not visible because it is outside the chart. It is enough if you change label alignment.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    align: 'center'
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kr9fyq21/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.align